# Git log group create/modified files

Tags: git, git-log

I need to get a report based on git commits that shows all the files that were created and modified during a specific period of time and by a specific author. These files should be grouped in these 2 categories (Created|Modified).

Currently I'm using this [script](https://gist.github.com/dmegorov/b64dcea2eed31e02c916fc6ed9111f4f) to group the files by commit and I'm still not able to identify if the file was created or modified.

Any help around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --author='Eduardo Hitek' \
        --since=01.Jan.2019 --before=01.Jan.2020 \
        --pretty= --name-status \
| sort -u
```

Comment: Great! That's can help me to get to the desired solution.